# How to remove contact and login

Tags: magento-1.9

How to remove the contact and the login?

[image: remove contact and inloggen]

Comment: Do you have this installed in a location we can access? 

A naive way of removing these would be by hiding the elements via CSS. Better advice may be possible when we have some more information regarding the webshop and its theme.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a quick a dirty method, you could remove these elements with CSS using display:none. Similarly, you can use javascript or jquery to remove the element from the DOM.

A cleaner was would be to locate the template rendering these elements. Template hints can be turned on by going logging in as admin and going to:

system->confirguration->developer->and then turning on 'template path hints'.

A frontend overlay should show up now telling you the template you need to look at. 
Copy that template into:

app/design/frontend/[yourtheme]/default/template/[template_path]

to override the core/base theme template. Here you could edit out the php/xHTML of that specific element.